# how to write htaccess file, to change URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

i am trying to convert the actual URL to user friendly there is dynamic menu, when user click on page the orignal url becomes

**`http://example.com/single.php?name=mypagename`**

i want to change it to

**`http://example.com/page/mypagename`**

here is my htaccess file i tried from different angles Please can any one help to correct it..

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /single\.php(\?|\ )
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.+)
RewriteRule page/(.*) single.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must rearrange your directives:

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ single.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(Web/2015/wessexcars)/internalpage\.php?seo=\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(Web/2015/wessexcars)/(.+?)/?$ $1/internalpage.php?seo=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: yes its working fine but, please can you help Please i am sending you link

Comment: Click on the page Car Rental, in the footer

Comment: but when you will click on home page and again, you click on car rental it creates problem; Thanks for help dear Please help to solve it

Comment: # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ single.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: above is full htaccess file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66888/discussion-between-engr-zardari-and-anubhava).

Comment: @anubava
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage.php?seo=winchester 
here is my Current URL i want to chage it in
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/winchester ,
help me to Write .htaccess file Please

Comment: I have added more rules but please don't add new questions from comments section. Better to open up a new question for new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like bellow,

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/page/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)$ $1/single.php?name=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: Please Edit whole file

Answer (score 0):

firstly change your config file make index file blank

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and make a htaccess file

```
    <ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </ifmodule>
```